# Model Binding in ASHX?

Tags: asp.net, ashx

I have a .NET 3.5 webform project and want to add a generic handler (ashx) to accept ajax calls. My current implementation has me parsing out the Request object (ex. Request["param"]) in the handler in order to obtain all querystring values. Is there a better way to do this? I know MVC projects have model binding capabilities and would love to utilze that same feature in a generic handler. Is this possible?

Overall, what is the best way to grab querystring parameters in a generic handler?

Comment: well MVC (i believe) uses reflection to construct the raw http params into a strongly-typed object. you could always grab the mvc source and take a look/implement something similar for ashx. if all else fails, just create a helperwhich would then inspect the request params and return a strongly typed object from that. what is your ashx serving anyway? html? json? xml? images?

Comment: thank you, it is serving json

Answer (score 0):

Just simply by using Request.QueryString.Get(); you could build the MVC model binding process for web forms, but that isn't available out of the box.  Plus, how many handlers do you write?  If only a few, a complex process like that may be overhead.

HTH.